# How to isolate different parts of a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm using an API (`https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?`) that gets me this object (a random quote with author):

```
?({"quoteText":"Life is so constructed that an event does not, cannot, will not, match the expectation. ","quoteAuthor":"Charlotte Bronte","senderName":"","senderLink":"","quoteLink":"http://forismatic.com/en/16af75b8b4/"})
```

How would I be able to isolate `Life is so constructed that an event does not, cannot, will not, match the expectation.` from `"quoteText":` and place it somewhere in my HTML code.

Same thing with isolating: `Charlotte Bronte` from `"quoteAuthor":` and placing it somewhere in my HTML code. Bonus points, sometimes the `"quoteAuthor":` field is left blank, not sure what to do when that happens.

I know how to place this entire JSON object in my HTML code, I just need some help isolating certain parts of the JSON object, and placing them separately.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: **JSON.parse()** will help you. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp . So basically you will convert this string representation into a valid `object` and then access the values via its property names.

Comment: what you mean by isolating? If its a json you can just access to the keys of the object `jsonObject.quoteText` will return `Life is so constructed that an event does not, cannot, will not...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: What is the questionmark in front? It is not a valid JSON object with this questionmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are retrieving in JSONp format, remember that you need to set the `dataType` to `jsonp` so that jQuery can parse it properly. Once you have done that, in the `jqXHR.done` callback you can simply access the actual JSON response.

What you receive is simply an **object**, which contains data in the format of **key-value pairs**. In order to access the value, say `Life is so constructed that...`, you will have to retrieve it by its key, which is `quoteText`. Using dot notation and assuming that the object is stored in a variable, say `response`, then the quote can be accessed using `response.quoteText`. See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
$(function() {
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp'});
    
  request.done(function(response) {
    // 'response' is the entire JSON returned
    console.log(response.quoteText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access certain keys from a JSON object by using the `.` "operator".

In your case, let's say you saved the JSON in a `var` called `quote`, `quote.quoteText` would equal `"Life is so constructed that an event does not, cannot, will not, match the expectation. "`

```js
var quote = {"quoteText":"Life is so constructed that an event does not, cannot, will not, match the expectation. ","quoteAuthor":"Charlotte Bronte","senderName":"","senderLink":"","quoteLink":"http://forismatic.com/en/16af75b8b4/"};

document.querySelector("#div").innerHTML = quote.quoteText;
document.querySelector("#from").innerHTML = quote.quoteAuthor;
```

```html
Quote:
<pre id="div"></pre>

From: <span id="from"></span>
```

You should look into [w3school's JSON tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)